# Freeze distilling homemade wine

Tags: country-wine

If I freeze distill my homemade wine would it be considered brandy or fortified wine ? I like this method better than using a still with a flame .

Comment: U dont have to use flame u can even get a simple water disteller

Answer (score 4):

It would not be fortified as you are not adding alcohol to it, thereby fortifying it.

It would be more akin to a Brandy on a technical level as you are using a methoid of distilation to concentrate the alcohol.

But, my guess is it would leave you with a drink more similar to a fortified wine sherry/port than a brandy as freeze distilling to 30%+ is difficult, has heavy losses and it time consuming.

Be aware that freeze distilation does not allow for the removal of heads and tails, so you run the risk of concentrating toxic alcohols, usually not a great worry but something to be mindful of.

Comment: "*has heavy losses*" — The ice doesn't have to be discarded; it works quite well as an ice-cube substitute in fruit drinks.

Comment: It can also get very slushy, and the alcohol get a gem-like clarity. Ice nucleates on imperfections, and thus removing ice/slush removes the bits of stuff that can make it cloudy.